# Groovy SQL statement syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, groovy, soapui

I am attempting to create a groovy script that will extract a value from a table in a database, that will then be used in a request in SOPAUI.

The issue is that within my SQL query, I have a where clause that includes a string value with single quotes,that when is run will return an error.

```
     import groovy.sql.Sql
     import java.sql.Driver


    def sql = Sql.newInstance     ('jdbc:sqlserver://hostname\\INSTANCE1;Database=DB;integratedSecurity=true','com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
    row = sql.firstRow('SELECT TOP 1  m.ID [DB].[dbo].[AOTableName] AS m INNER JOIN [DOC_MASTER_dev].[dbo].[AOMatterTableName] AS c ON m.SystemID = c.ID  WHERE  (m.Status = 0) AND (c.Code = "'ESB'") order by newid(), m.DateAddedForReplication desc ')
```

.......

The error is below:

> ERROR:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:       startup failed:
>   Script25.groovy: 6: unexpected token: ESB @ line 6, column 231.
>      us = 0) AND (c.Code = "'ESB'") ord
>                                    ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: ESB @ line 6, column 231.
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(......

The rest of the script will just convert into a string and set value from DB as property that can then be used in the request.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to read this: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be a missing FROM ?

SELECT TOP 1  m.ID **FROM** [DB].[dbo].[AOTableName] AS m etc...

plus a double vs single quote problem in : AND (c.Code = **"'ESB'"**)

should be : AND (c.Code = **\'ESB\'**)

Comment: Typo on my part and that is why I was missing the 'FROM'. Thanks it worked - c.Code = \'ESB\')